# Cannot convert undefined or null to object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have already a write function I am stacking one error. I can't understand why this error occurring. Please help me here-

```
const Object11 = {
  name: 'Walton Business Class Soundless High Speed Niico Fan - Mint - 9 Inch',
  category: '630c5db82cc1c55ae7cde3a3',
  subCategory: [],
  brand: '630c5e382cc1c55ae7cde3d5',
  unit: 'Pcs',
  tag: [],
  refundAble: false,
  productImages: [
    {
      url: 'https://nekmart.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/Products/l7ugtc2f202289183910167l7ugtc2g.jpeg'
    }
  ],
  youtubeLink: null,
  price: 23235,
  flash: '',
  discount: 23,
  discountUnit: 'flat',
  quantity: 23,
  description: '<p></p>\n',
  attributes: [],
  visibility: true,
  meta: { title: '', description: '' },
  showStock: true,
  tax: 0,
  taxUnit: 'flat',
  disclaimer: 'The actual color of the physical product may slightly vary due to the deviation of lighting sources, photography or your device display settings. Delivery charges may vary as per the location, Product Size and Weight; we will notify before proceeding the delivery.'
}
```

And then I write this function-

```
function rec(obj) {
    for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        if (obj[key] === '') {
            delete obj[key];
        } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            obj[key] = rec(obj[key]);
            // if (obj[key] && Object.keys(obj[key]).length === 0) delete obj[key];
            console.log(Object.keys(obj[key]))
        }
    }
    return Array.isArray(obj) ? obj.filter(val => val) : obj;
}
```

I call this function with that object-

```
const productUpdateInput = rec(productUpdateInput);
```

But I am getting this error-
`Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Error throws from this line-

```
if (obj[key] && Object.keys(obj[key]).length === 0) delete obj[key];
console.log(Object.keys(obj[key]))
```

But I can't understand what is the problem. Why I am getting this type of error.

**Note- When I put above object then I found this error otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your object contains a `null` value (i.e. `youtubeLink: null,`)
2. Then you call the `rec` function with `obj[key] = rec(obj[key]);` where `key === 'youtubeLink'`, which is `rec(null)`.
3. Then the `rec` functions tries to do `Object.keys(obj)`, or `Object.keys(null)`, which throws an error.

One solution would be to shortcut the function if `obj` is `null` or `undefined`.

```
function rec(obj) {
    if (obj === null || obj === undefined) return obj;
    for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        if (obj[key] === '') {
            delete obj[key];
        } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            obj[key] = rec(obj[key]);
            // if (obj[key] && Object.keys(obj[key]).length === 0) delete obj[key];
            console.log(Object.keys(obj[key]))
        }
    }
    return Array.isArray(obj) ? obj.filter(val => val) : obj;
}
```

**UPDATE**: if you want to clean the object of any empty values, then do not re-invent the wheel (unless you are doing an educational exercise), and use an existing module that has been tested for that purpose. For example [clean-deep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-deep), [remove-empty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remove-empty), etc.

Comment: I also want to be delete if object key will null or undefined

Comment: @MdAli see my updated answer.

Comment: `clean-deep`, `remove-empty` doesn't support typescript. Is there any with typescript?

Comment: @MdAli what do you mean it "doesn't support typescript"? Are you using npm or yarn to add the package to your project, and aren't you doing `import clean from 'clean-deep';` ? Node modules do not need to be TypeScript, and clean-deep does have a `.d.ts` file declaring it's interface.